# AngularJS + Service Stack Query Return Type

Tags: c#, servicestack

Am currently using Service Stack to retrieve data from a local DB using the following controller function:

```
 // GET: /Checklist/GetChecklists
        public IEnumerable<Checklist> GetChecklists()
        {
           var dbFactory = new ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteConnectionFactory(SqliteFileDb, new SqlServerOrmLiteDialectProvider(), true);
            using (var db = dbFactory.Open())
            {
                var retObj = db.Select<Checklist>();
                return retObj;
            }
        }
```

Which successfully [retrieves data](http://oi62.tinypic.com/2ir4qvp.jpg) from my DB.

The issue is the function is always returning the *type* of the data rather than the actual data itself.

Eg: 
[Example 1](http://oi60.tinypic.com/krkuc.jpg)
[Example 2](http://oi62.tinypic.com/24o8yft.jpg)

What must be done so that the function actually returns the data itself rather than the type?

Thanks

Comment: That code looks OK. But where is the actual action method? The method in your ServiceStack service that calls `GetChecklists()` and returns it's result?

Comment: Hi again Scott. I'm calling that function directly from my (app.js) javascript file (that could be the problem??). There is no action method I'm routing through. The following shows almost the entirety of the code: http://oi58.tinypic.com/2rnua8x.jpg

Comment: Did you resolve this issue?

Comment: Hi Scott, I ended up taking a slightly different approach but this help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using ServiceStack.ORMLite but your are not using ServiceStack, you are using WebApi.

In your screenshot I can see that your `ChecklistController` inherits from `Controller` but for WebApi it should inherit from `ApiController` for the serialization to work.

I would also add the verb attribute to the method:

```cs
public class ChecklistController : ApiController
{
    ...

    [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Checklist> GetChecklists()
    {
        ...
    }
```

In your `WebApiConfig` you will want to ensure you [have a route setup](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api). Typically WebApi is prefixed with `api` this is to avoid conflict with the MVC routing.

```cs
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "API Default",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Then make your call to **/api**/Checklist/GetChecklists